# Find GCD $(10^6\times 6^2 \times 5 ; 6 \times 15 \times 3^7)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find GCD $(10^6\times 6^2 \times 5 ; 6 \times 15 \times 3^7)$

I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write
$$
10^6\cdot 6^2\cdot 5 = 2^8\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^7
$$
$$
6\cdot 15\cdot 3^7 = 2\cdot 3^9\cdot 5
$$
Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

From @prahlad-vaidyanathan:

$10^6\cdot 6^2\cdot 5 = 2^8\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^7 \\
6\cdot 15\cdot 3^7 = 2\cdot 3^9\cdot 5$

So,

$gcd(10^6\cdot 6^2 \cdot 5 , 6 \cdot 15 \cdot 3^7)\\= gcd(2^8\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^7,2\cdot 3^9\cdot 5)\\=2\cdot 3^2\cdot5\cdot gcd(2^7\cdot5^6,3^7)\\=2\cdot 3^2\cdot5\cdot 1\\= 2\cdot 3^2\cdot5  $

Or, directly
$gcd(2^8\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^7,2\cdot 3^9\cdot 5)=2^1 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1=2\cdot 3^2\cdot5$    // *(minimum of exponent)*

---

Answer (score -1):

My bad. I was wrong in counting number of factors for 2nd number. Edited the correct answer

Your expression is same like 
$$(2^9 \times 3^3 \times 5^7 , 2 \times 3^9 \times 5)$$
which can be divided by the largest number 
$$(2 \times 3^3 \times 5)$$

So the GCD is $$(2 \times 3^3 \times 5)$$ which is equal to $90$.